# Meta key in Big Sur

Tags: macos, iterm2

I have changed the option key to meta in iterm2, but the meta key is not working, but writing signs like a question marks. (see in the screenshot).

In the terminal the meta key is working when toggled in preferences.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Dec 2020:
I solved this problem by using the `ESC+` option in iterm2. When I press Option, the meta key is executed. I do not understand why though!